# WMS for layergroup in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

We are trying to get single wms layer from Geoserver. We know how to pick out the wms but we want to be able to pick out wms for layergroup that we have created within our geoserver.

- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/virtual-services.html

Here we can pick out wms from a layer or a workspace but not from layergroups.

Is it possible to create wms from layergroup in Geoserver?

Sjonni, Iceland

Comment: a layergroup works exactly like a layer from the client's point of view. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Ok, We have here a layer: http://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/IS50V/samgongur_linur/wms?
"IS50V" is the workspace and "samgongur_linur" is the layer - that works fine.

If i put the layergroup instead:
http://gis.lmi.is/geoserver/IS50V/IS_50V_samgongur/wms?
then "IS50V" is the workspace and "IS_50V_samgongur" is the layergroup - that doesn´t work.

I hope I am clear enough :=)

Comment: layergroups don't have workspaces.

Comment: It appears to have workspace: 
http://gis.lmi.is/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 1):

According to this link it is not yet possible:
http://ehc.ac/p/geoserver/mailman/message/32091487/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. I have followed successfully [this documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layergroups.html). At the end you will have a layer (the layer group) exposed in the geoserver wms service.

1. create a layerGroup as explained in the example post;
2. check if it is all right in the "layer preview" section;
3. Pick out wms with the Virtual OWS Services.

Comment: Can you give me an example - I am not getting this :)

Comment: I have already edited my answer.You have to consider the Layergroup WMS as a single layer WMS.